# Disabling time and timezone at ionic date input

Tags: php, angularjs, date, ionic-framework, timezone

I'm using angularjs and ionic on frontent and php (slim) at the backend.
html:

```
<input type="date" name="birthday" ng-model="user.birthday" required>
```

php:

```
$app->post('/auth/signup', function () use ($app, $user_model, $config) {
    $data = json_decode($app->request()->getBody(), true);
    error_log($data['birthday']); //1111-11-10T20:00:00.000Z
```

I have a date field for getting birth date. But when it posts, I want it to just post "**1111-11-11**" but it posts as "**Date {Sat Nov 11 1111 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (EET)}**". When I get print from php it becomes "**1111-11-10T22:00:00.000Z**" because of the timezone difference, date changes.

I couldn't find how to fix the situation. I want the date roller, so I don't want to seperate day - month - year fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code, php or js (depends on where you want to get help).

Comment: I added the code for the related parts.

Comment: Try `$dt = new DateTimeImmutable($data['birthday']); error_log($dt->format('Y-m-d'));`

Comment: it gave "1111-11-10".

data['birthday'] is already "1111-11-10T22:00:00.000Z". Probably because of that.

Comment: As you pass `1111-11-10T20:00:00.000Z` it's totally OK. You have to pass a timezone to have the same value on server side.

Comment: Passing timezone was a good idea but it gave different problems which may be because of me.

I fixed the situation with passing the field's modified value (1111-11-11) to another variable before submit.
Thanks for your help.